# Is there a way to use a string inside of a variable to refer to an object property?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Basically I want to use an object to hold certain dates. For example:

```
var date {
  jan26: 'Today this happened'
};
```

Then get the current date and put it into a string. For example: `var today = 'jan26';`. Then use that to refer to the object property: For example: `alert(date.today);` Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which part are you exactly needing help with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code: 
`date[today]`

Comment: Care to explain __why__!

Comment: Didn't think about using bracket notation. Thanks Leo!